# Using DATEADD instead of less than or equal to when testing against parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm newer to SQL and I'm playing around with some existing queries in my database in SSMS - something I've been coming across lately is this line:

```
WHERE DE.Modified >=@FromDate
AND DE.Modified < DATEADD(DAY,1,@ToDate)
```

Where `FromDate` and `ToDate` are given parameters. What I'm wondering is why one might write the second line instead of:

```
AND DE.Modified <=@ToDate
```

Is it a best practice in SQL to only use the less than operator and test against a date + 1, or are these the exact same?

EDIT:

`FromDate` and `ToDate` are declared as `DATETIME`:

```
DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME 
    ,   @ToDate DATETIME
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would write this to handle any time component on `Modified`.

In your version, anything that happens during the day of `@ToDate` would be missed.

Comment: Ah that makes sense... so if I were using a `ToDate` parameter for today's date (12/30/2019), I'd be missing any records with that date using my `<=@ToDate` example?

Answer (score 1):

The two are different:

```sql
   DE.Modified <=@ToDate
```

checks if the `Modified` date is less than the `ToDate`, while

```
     DE.Modified < DATEADD(DAY,1,@ToDate)
```

checks if the `Modified` date is less than the **day after** the `ToDate`. That is, the `ToDate` plus one day.

Comment: You are assuming datetime and not date data type

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on why `DE.Modified <=@ToDate` only checks if `Modified` is less than the `ToDate` when the operator is `<=`? I would expect a literal "less than or equal to" here.

Comment: @KeithL I should've clarified in the post that `FromDate` and `ToDate` are declared as `DATETIME`, sorry about that.

Comment: @dwirony daShier (and Gordon) are both assuming the relatively common situation where datetime types are actually only holding date values, and that the normal intent of todate equal to '2019-12-30 00:00:00' is not to include only the first second of that date, but the whole date.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip when dealing with dates, usually try to compare

```
WHERE DATEDIFF('d',DE.Modified,@FromDate) >= 0
AND DATEDIFF('d',DE.Modified,@ToDate) <= 0
```

It won't mater much here but its a good habit because when you will be working on procedures or queries where you can build a calculated column, that column can then be indexed. And it will make your applications that much faster.
Also, you clearly know what you are comparing (days, hours, etc) as Gordon said above.